# Converting invoice image to editable format

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am creating software to convert invoice images to an editable format (converting both, text and tabular data). So far, I have found contours in python to convert image to smaller chunks which help in finding location of text, Tesseract is used to convert those images to text.

I have extracted the text but now the issue is to put those text on known positions in a simple notepad or word document or any other you suggest.

Example invoices:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

i Would Suggest You to use **pytesseract** its  Simple Python Optical Character Recognition Here is a Sample Code

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

im = Image.open("temp.jpg") # the second one 
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
im.save('temp2.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp2.jpg'))
print(text)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it only convert image to text, the problem i am facing is to put that text on desired location or create table to maintain the orignal layout of invoice image...

Comment: is the Format yo have is Restricted to Png only ??

Comment: if You Have HTML Format or PDF Format then you Can use                                                                                           for HTML: https://pypi.org/project/html-table-extractor/                                                           for PDF : https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/                                                                                         These get the Contect in Exact Format

Comment: try this https://medium.com/@winston.smith.spb/python-ocr-for-pdf-or-compare-textract-pytesseract-and-pyocr-acb19122f38c